# Call library functions with varying number of inputs while keeping API simple

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework, asp.net-core

For a ASP.NET Core application, I'm using a library which performs calculations using objects that have a similar interface but their constructors use different inputs. The inputs are market prices and volatilities.

```
public class Base 
{
    public virtual double Method1();
    public virtual double Method2();
}

public class BaseOne : Base 
{
    public override double Method1();
    public override double Method2();
}

public class BaseTwo : Base 
{
    public override double Method1();
    public override double Method2();
}

public class ConcreteOneA : BaseOne
{
    public ConcreteOneA(double F, double V, double r, double K, ...);
    public override double Method1() { // code }
    public override double Method2() { // code }
}
public class ConcreteOneB : BaseOne
{
    public ConcreteOneA(double F, double V, double r, double K, ...);
    public override double Method1() { // code }
    public override double Method2() { // code }
}
public class ConcreteTwoA : BaseTwo
{
    public ConcreteOneA(double F1, double F2, double V, double r, double K, ...);
    public override double Method1() { // code }
    public override double Method2() { // code }
}
```

To create the ConcreteOne and ConcreteTwo classes, I have to fetch the F, F1, F2, and V inputs from a SQL Server database. I have a EF Core DbContext entity which is injected into a ASP.NET Core controller.

Every time, I want to perform calculations, my code was littered with DbContext queries and filters. Also I wanted to be able to use a single controller action to compute values for Method1 and Method2, since these methods are similar to all the Concrete classes, and it provided for a convenient API interface for the users. So I created a factory class:

```
public class BaseFactory
{
    private MyContext _context;
    public BaseFactory(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public Base FromCode(MyDbEntity obj)
    {
        // use the context object to fetch F and V, and also F1 and F2 if the obj type is 3 
       //...

        // compute the other inputs for the concrete constructors which can be obtained directly from the MyDbEntity obj
       // ...

        switch (obj.Code)
        {
            case "1":
            case "4":
                return new ConcreteOneA(F, V, ....rest of the parameters computed from obj...
            case "5":
                return new ConcreteOneB(F,V, ....rest of the parameters computed from obj...);
            case "3":
                return new ConcreteTwoA(F1, F2, V, ......rest computed from obj.....);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the right approach? The F is the price and V is the volatility which might need to come from a different data source in the future, so I could need to create another factory method for that specific source. But is it a good idea to make the factory dependent on this DbContext? My controller passes the injected DbContext into the factory when the controller is created:

```
[ApiController]
public class MyController
{
    public MyDbContext _context;
    private BaseFactory factory;
    public MyController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        factory = new BaseFactory(_context);
    }
    [HttpGet('/route1')]
    public ActionResult<double> MyMethodCompute(string code, double m, double s, double p)
    {
        // use _context to get MyDbEntity obj...

        return factory.FromCode(obj).Method1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks sensible to me. Does this design allow to inject a "mock" db context object, for testing the factory or the controller without using a real database?

Comment: That's what I've been wondering too. If the controller didn't inject the DbContext into the factory, how can I get the ASP.NET DI Container to inject it for me?

Comment: Honestly, if you don't know what `MyDbContext` is and if it can be replaced by a mock, how shall we? In case it cannot be replaced, encapsulate it inside of some kind of repository class which abstracts the database away.

Comment: Yeah MyDbContext should be replaceable. I could just use the EF Core InMemory database provider for testing

Comment: I don't know if making the factory dependent on the context is a good idea though

Comment: If the db context is replaceable by an InMemory db provider and allows easy testing, do you have requirement for the factory to produce those objects from a different datasource than a database? If the answer is "currently not", then it is perfectly fine that the factory depends on the db context. If the answer is "yes", you may need a more general datasource abstraction, but somewhere do the input parameters have to come from.

Comment: Unfortunately, yeah, the factory will need to obtain the F and V values from some other data source in the future. Would I be creating a new factory in that situation? My controller action would have to change

Comment: If this is just "in the future", I would probably wait until the time is ready, then create the second factory, but refactor any common code into a place like a common base class for both factories.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its a correct approach.

Essentially you are instantiating an object from a db where the object could be one of several child classes.

A factory is a common way of achieving this.

> But is it a good idea to make the factory dependent on this DbContext

Yes. I would always abstract the database into a repository. However, repositories are supposed to return business objects, so in this case the repository and factory would be the same thing and of course a repository needs DB access.

Comment: _" However, repositories are supposed to return business objects, so in this case the repository and factory would be the same thing"_ Just because two services both return the same type does not mean that they are the same thing. The repository is concerned with how to instantiate a given entity of a given type, but a factory can (as would be the case for OP) be tasked with _deciding which concrete type to return_. That is not the reponsibility of a repository. Essentially, you'll have many repo methods (one per concrete type), and a single factory method that chooses which repo method to use

Comment: I feel like you are ignoring the "in this case" bit. Its pretty common to have a repo return different sub classes based on type column in the db, maybe reading the extra info out of extra tables, _in this case_ the factory and repository blend into a single class.